# Custom Search Taxonomy Block shows Terms for all Languages

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search

i have a vocabulary which has many terms . Some terms are for English and some are for arabic language . (vocabulary is translatable so each term can be translated)

I am displaying a "Custom Search Taxonomy Block" but it shows all terms from EN and AR in the dropdown ..

any idea how to restrict EN terms for EN site and AR for AR site ?

Thanks

Comment: What does Custom Search Taxonomy Block mean? A taxonomy block? or a custom block?

Comment: its a block which comes with https://drupal.org/project/custom_search